# Determining if pointer is on a valid boundary in a custom memory manager

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a CS assignment to write a basic memory manager in c++ using linked lists. The manager allocates pages of memory that each contain a fixed number of objects (all objects in this case are the same size), along with optional header bytes and padding on the ends of each block for debugging. Pages also contain a pointer to the next page of memory. As blocks are freed, they are added to a separate list of free objects, and new pages get allocated when memory is requested but the free list is empty.

I'm at the point where I'm freeing objects, and if a debug flag in the manager is set, I validate to make sure blocks are A) not already freed and B) on a valid block boundary. The first case I can deal with, but I can't figure out the second. The operation is supposed to be done in constant time (so I can't walk the pages to determine it), and outside of header bytes and padding (which a block may not have, depending on settings) I have no knowledge of what page an object is on or the surrounding objects.

Comment: Are you asking how to find out if an object is aligned correctly?  If so, it's basically `if (ptr % sizeof(T) == 0)`.